# Multiple JOINs with WHEREs and GROUP BYs on parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables, one parent and two children and I'm trying to construct a query that aggregates fields from all 3 grouped by and filtered by expressions entirely dependent on the parent table. To help understand the tables, the second child has a foreign key in the first child and parent; the first child has a foreign key in the parent. So e.g.

```
 parentTable | child1Table | child2Table
-------------+-------------+-------------
 id*         | id*         | id
 ...         | subId*      | subId
 ...         | ...         | uniqueId*
```

Where the `*`s show what forms the primary key.

I see two ways of doing this:

```
SELECT allAggregates
FROM (
    SELECT exprOnParentFields, parentAggregates
    FROM parentTable
    WHERE conditionOnParentRecord GROUP BY exprOnParentFields
  ) full_p
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT p.exprOnParentFields, c1.child1Aggregates
    FROM child1Table c1 LEFT JOIN parentTable p ON c1.id = p.id
    WHERE p.conditionOnParentRecord GROUP BY p.exprOnParentFields
  ) full_c1 ON full_p.exprOnParentFields = full_c1.exprOnParentFields
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT p.exprOnParentFields, c2.child2Aggregates
    FROM child2Table c2 LEFT JOIN parentTable p ON c2.id = p.id
    WHERE p.conditionOnParentRecord GROUP BY p.exprOnParentFields
  ) full_c2 ON full_p.exprOnParentFields = full_c2.exprOnParentFields
```

Notice that `exprOnParentFields` is the same everywhere and so is `conditionOnParentRecord`. Furthermore, if it matters, neither is necessarily simple (i.e. just one column name). I do not like this method because of the repetition of those two things.

The alternate version:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE filteredIds AS (
  SELECT id, exprOnParentFields AS groupExpr
  FROM parentTable WHERE conditionOnParentRecord);

SELECT allAggregates
FROM (
    SELECT f.groupExpr, p.parentAggregates
    FROM parentTable p INNER JOIN filteredIds f ON p.id = f.id
    GROUP BY f.exprOnParentFields
  ) full_p
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT f.groupExpr, c1.child1Aggregates
    FROM child1Table c1 INNER JOIN filteredIds f ON c1.id = f.id
    GROUP BY f.groupExpr
  ) full_c1 ON full_p.groupExpr = full_c1.groupExpr
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT f.groupExpr, c2.childAggregates
    FROM child2Table c2 INNER JOIN filteredIds f ON c2.id = f.id
    GROUP BY f.groupExpr
  ) full_c2 ON full_p.groupExpr = full_c2.groupExpr
```

This saves from expanding out the full `exprOnParentFields` for every join (now it's just the field names `groupExpr`) and eliminates the repetition of `conditionOnParentRecord`. However at the cost of creating the temporary and really it doesn't eliminate as much as I hoped. My [multipart] question is thus:

Is one of these preferred from a stylistic perspective? From a speed perspective?
Or even better, is there an all around different and better way to do this?

Important to note is that I cannot do one single 3 part join due to aggregation on repeated rows.

Comment: I don't think you can use `#filteredIds` in MySQL. Are you sure that's the DBMS you're using?

Comment: Thank you, was sandboxing in different dbms, ultimately this needs to work in MySQL. Question edited to reflect this.

Comment: Can we see some sample data and your desired output?

Comment: The second version won't work. MySQL has a stupid restriction that you can't refer to the same temporary table twice in the same query. This is one of the most obvious reasons to create temp tables, and you can't use it.

Comment: But you can do it if you make it a real table. You should give it an index on the `id` field to speed up the joins.

Comment: Barmar, you might just have enough there to make a full answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **"No"**. Generally speaking, I don't know of a simpler or more efficient way to form your query. If each table you are joining to is dependent on all of the tables "before it", then you pretty much have to use SQL as you stated.

Depending on how often the data changes, and how close to real-time the answer needs to be, you *could* build out temporary copies of the data that were pre-aggregated on your `exprOnParentFields` expression so that you could join on that pre-aggregated value (i.e. *many* queries using the result of *one* computation).

Of course, to compare the pros/cons of this (and anything), you should always use execution plans and traces to tell you how much work the db is really doing.

Good luck!

Comment: Was afraid this was going to be the answer. I will probably end up making a full table for this then.